# What is the rule for time between an IPO filing and public exchange

Tags: ipo

What is the time between an IPO filing (thinking S-1 registration and having a lead underwriter) and being traded on the public exchanges?

slide 9 here shows a calendar http://www.slideshare.net/samanthachmelik/The-IPO-Process-IC-Training

but I'm not sure what part is "IPO filing" and which part is "public trading"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a fixed nor predictable amount of time and will depend on market conditions.  If a company files appropriate paperwork to declare the intent to go public, but then the market sours, it would not be unusual for a company to push back their IPO until a later time.

Comment: okay, company puts out S-1, *can* their shares be trading the next day?